# Inserting Python Dict to MariaDB giving Error 1064

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

Having a dict of structured_files variable as below;

```
structured_files = {'158795_1635509614542_20211029151335135_27.1943_38.4319.jpg': ['158795', '1635509614542', '20211029151335135', '27.1943', '38.4319'], '2773170_1635255851988_20211026164412576_27.1836_38.4777.jpg': ['2773170', '1635255851988', '20211026164412576', '27.1836', '38.4777'], '2777171_1635330525915_20211027132846547_27.1875_38.4720.jpg': ['2777171', '1635330525915', '20211027132846547', '27.1875', '38.4720'], '2779392_1635150026780_20211025112027410_27.1627_38.4724.jpg': ['2779392', '1635150026780', '20211025112027410', '27.1627', '38.4724'], '3724797_1634893471399_20211022120432057_27.1334_38.5426.jpg': ['3724797', '1634893471399', '20211022120432057', '27.1334', '38.5426'], '5218186_1635161250087_20211025142730572_27.0694_38.4943.jpg': ['5218186', '1635161250087', '20211025142730572', '27.0694', '38.4943'], '5347212_1634987405913_20211023141006566_27.0454_38.5138.jpg': ['5347212', '1634987405913', '20211023141006566', '27.0454', '38.5138'], '8174846_1635335281021_20211027144801672_27.1039_38.3572.jpg': ['8174846', '1635335281021', '20211027144801672', '27.1039', '38.3572'], '9179383_1635321573332_20211027105933968_27.1251_38.3576.jpg': ['9179383', '1635321573332', '20211027105933968', '27.1251', '38.3576']}
```

Trying to insert in to mysql db code is follows;
For Creation;

```
Qcreate1 = "CREATE TABLE data_11 (id_key LONGTEXT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, date VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, sample VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, coord_y VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, coord_x VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, created datetime NOT NULL, key_id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT )"
```

For Inserting;

```
cols = list(structured_files.keys())
vals = list(structured_files.values())

Q1 = f"INSERT INTO data_11 {cols} values {vals}"

mycursor.execute(Q1)
```

It gives the error : `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '['158795_1635509614542_20211029151335135_27.1943_38.4319.jpg', '2773170_16352...' at line 1`

Why is that ?

Comment: Take a look at the string in the `Q1` variable after you have formatted it. Does it look like [valid INSERT syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/)?

Comment: Can you point the correct syntax or what is the wrong syntax here ? Can't i pass fstring to mycursor.execute() ? Couldn't figure out from the link you send.

Comment: MySQL doesn't care that you used an f-string, but the string has to be valid SQL syntax. Your usage of f-strings to interpolate a Python array does not produce valid SQL syntax.

Comment: How can i pass the whole dict without f strings couldn't done it  for hours ?

Comment: And @BillKarwin as you are expert i got another question i wanted to ask can you please answer ? Before making a list as in the question i made a nested list  but when i googled general answer is i cannot pass nested list into the mysql is this info right?

Comment: @BillKarwin it is not the nested list i was asking it was "Nested DİCT". Sorry and thank you

Comment: I can't even tell what you are intending this code to do. I can guess that each dict entry should result in a row to insert, with the key stored in column `id_key`, then the members of the array value stored in columns `name`, `date`, `sample`, `coord_y`, and `coord_x` of the respective row. Is my guess correct?

Comment: Your guess is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I tested this code to do what you want:

```
Q1 = "INSERT INTO data_11 (id_key, name, date, sample, coord_y, coord_x) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

for id_key, values in structured_files.items():
    cursor.execute(Q1, [id_key] + values)

cnx.commit()
```

Tips:

- Write the column names explicitly in the INSERT statement. Learn the syntax for INSERT:

  ```
  INSERT INTO <table> (<columns>) VALUES (<values>)
  ```

  Your `id_key`, the key in the dict, isn't a column name. It's one of the values, so it belongs in the `VALUES` clause.

  This is the syntax for inserting one row. Once you get used to this, you can explore multi-row INSERT syntax.
- Don't use f-strings to interpolate variables into the INSERT string, because that risks SQL injection flaws. Leave the values as placeholders as I showed, then pass the values *separately* as a list in the second argument to `cursor.execute()`.